# Watson conversation in nodejs giving ETIMEDOUT error

Tags: node.js, watson-conversation

Hello everyone I'm trying to test an example similar to [Watson Conversation Example](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#send_message), but with my workspace id and my own credentials of course, but I'm getting in every call the following error:

> { code: 'ETIMEDOUT',   errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',   syscall: 'connect',
>   address: '158.85.132.88',   port: 443 }

Could anyone have any idea of what is going on here, please?

Comment: Does the error still prevail? Does this happen also when you try to deploy conversation simple app ( https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple )? Could it be that the platform you are using does not support/has SSL turned off?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I don't know what happened, but now Watson Conversation Service is responding well.